# Chinese Post man problem

Tags: graph-theory

[image: Graph image]

I am trying to solve the chinese postman problem of the graph, i.e., find a delivery route with minimal distance. I have noticed that A, B, F, and D are odd vertices. I know there are three ways to pair them, but after that I am lost as to what to do.

Comment: Do you want a closed circuit visiting every vertex? Can you backtrack?

Comment: yes and yes. the goal is to find the minimal distance needed to travel to each vertex, and through each edge and end where you started

Comment: So if you need to use every edge then presumably you will want to duplicate AF, and BGD at an additional cost of $1+(2+3)=6$ and then build a Eulerian circuit such as ABCDEFGHAFHBDGBGDFA.  There is no cheaper way to connect A to any of the other three and to connect D to any of the other three

Comment: I duplicated A, B, F, and D since they are odd vertices. Why duplicate G?

Comment: Because the cheapest route from D to any of A,B,F is to B via G

Comment: so i've got the minimum weight to be 43

Comment: I suspect the original graph has a total weight of $48$ and if I add $6$ I get $54$